# Dynamic changing of Language in QML view

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qqmlcomponent

In my project, there is a language page with four language options. If we change them, entire application language and some images changes. My problem is is there any signal/ callback to switch resources as like in Android or any some other mechanism we should follow for this QML?

Comment: read https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-internationalization.html

Comment: There is a tutorial in the Qt wiki explaining how to achieve this : https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_do_dynamic_translation_in_QML Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

To do what you need, first, get familiar with [official documentation on Internationalization and Localization with Qt Quick](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-internationalization.html).

Next you need to wrap all strings that should be translated into `qsTr`. Then, here is simplified code of switching languages:

```
void Settings::switchToLanguage(const QString &language)
{
    if (!m_translator.isEmpty())
        QCoreApplication::removeTranslator(&m_translator);
    m_translator.load(QStringLiteral(":/language_") + language));
    QCoreApplication::installTranslator(&m_translator));
    m_engine->retranslate();
}
```

According to article [New in Qt 5.10: Dynamic Language Change in QML](https://www.embeddeduse.com/2017/11/12/new-in-qt-5-10-dynamic-language-change-in-qml/).